# I want to add camera to my emulator but My emulator has not hardware options

Tags: android, eclipse, android-camera, android-virtual-device

1. Where is hardware choose? I don't find and I don't add camera my  emulator

Comment: what emulator are you using?

Comment: Android 4.1.2 Apı Level:16 - 4.0 WVGA (480*800:hdpi)

Comment: better to use device ,

Comment: For example please ? :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First connect you webcam with PC and check it is working or not.
Then select back camera option to Webcam and save this configuration
and start your AVD.

Comment: Thanks a lot ROHIT PARMAR , I fix it

Comment: I want to ask question . I want to input characters text plain fields but text plain is not active in emulator . What should I do?